# Prove a function is surjective or injective

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

so I'm having trouble figuring out why this question is surjective / where $0$ comes from.

$f : \mathbb{N} \longrightarrow \mathbb{N}$ where $f(x) = x + 1$.

so given N begins from $0$ it goes:
Source - Target
$0 - 1$
$1 - 2$
$2 - 3$
$3 - 4$

Does $0$ have no pre-image come from the target not starting with $0$? Or can someone explain what?

the answer states :

$f$ is not onto because $0$ has no pre-image.

cheers

Comment: What is meant by $N_7$?

Comment: someone edited my comment and did it wrong. It's meant to be arrow.

Comment: What makes you think it is surjective?

Comment: Originally I thought it was surjective since every number in the source is linked to something, but then I looked at the answer and it states it is not surjective as 0 has no pre-image

Comment: What do you think 0 is linked to? If we have $x+1=0$, then surely $x=-1 \not\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: it's linked to 1 isn't it? since x + 1 = 0 - 1?

Comment: I'm typing up a more complete answer now. But quick question: Do you include 0 as a natural number? Or are you starting with 1 as the first natural number?

Comment: we include 0 as a natural number for this course. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that for a function $f$ to be surjective we need
$$
\forall y \in CD(f) \exists x \in D(f) : f(x) = y
$$
where $CD(f)$ stands for the codomain of $f$ and $D(f)$ stands for the domain of $f$. In qualitative terms this means every element of the range is *hit* by the function.

Now you were on the correct path noting that $0$ will be a problem point in the range.

Now let's talk about our function $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ whereas $f(x) = x+1$. Let's assume that $f$ is surjective, then for any $y \in \mathbb{N}$ there is some element in the domain that causes $f$ to *hit* $y$. Since this should work for any $y \in \mathbb{N}$ it should work in particular for $y=0$ since $0 \in \mathbb{N}$. Now does there exist some $x \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $f(x) = y$?

Comment: ahhh so what you're saying is, Since N begins from 0. x + y means that in the source 0 exists, but since f(x) = x + 1; 
in the target 0 doesn't exist therefore it has no pre-image?

Comment: @Javanoob33 yes exactly. Note that in mathematical terms what you're considering the "target" is called the codomain, and what you consider the "source" is the domain.

Comment: Oh yeah that's right, okay awesome thank you heaps. Just to clarify if I've understood this correctly: 

Say we have F:Z ⟶ Z where f(x) = x2.
0,0
1,1
4,4

This would not be surjective as 2 doesn't exist in the range, therefore 2 has no pre-image?

Comment: @DanZimm Excellent point! Target is actually probably a better name for the co-domain of a function. The definitions of range/co-domain is such a muddled mess -- target makes intuitive sense.

Comment: @Javanoob33 exactly! I'm glad to see you've understood what I've said. Also to learn how to do proper math formatting check out this [link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @GammaFunction yea, I had never heard of this before this post (the terminology of target), but I sure will use it so that I can use the *hit* metaphor ;D

Comment: Awesome thanks DanZimm, appreciate your help.  I'll have a look at that link now. New to this site so I've always wondered how to do it. 

Yeah It's quite weird. Throughout my course we've been told Source(Domain) Target(Range) but whenever I google questions etc it comes up with co-domain etc. Gets quite confusing lol.

Comment: @Javanoob33 yea, note that the target is the *codomain* though, not the *range*. The *range* are the targets that are actually hit by the function.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** A function $f: X \to Y$ is surjective if for every $y \in Y$, there exists an $x \in X$ such that $f(x) = y$.

---

For this particular problem, we have that $f: \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ is defined by $f(x)=x+1$.

We run into trouble with $0$. We have that $0 \in \mathbb{N}$ so for $f$ to be surjective, it better be that $0$ is in the image of $f$. But if we suppose that $f(x)=1$, then

$$f(x) = x + 1 = 1.$$

Solving for $x$, we see that it must be that $x = -1$. But this is an issue as $-1 \in \mathbb{N}$, so it can't be that $0$ is in the image of $f$.

And thus, $f$ is no surjective because there exists an element in the co-domain of $f$ (namely 0) which is not "hit" by anything in the domain of $f$.

Comment: Sorry can you explain that in layman's terms? I understand what you're saying but I can't figure out how to apply that to answering the question?

Thanks

Comment: @Javanoob33 I added a bit more explanation. Let me know if it helps or if there is anything still tripping you up.

Comment: Thanks @Gamma Function, makes much more sense now. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

In order for a function to be surjective for every $y\in \mathbb{N}$ exists $x\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f(x)=y$ now $x+1=y$ which means $x=y-1$ we can express $x$ in function of $y$ now only thing we need to check is does $x$'s domain get violated by some $y$ taking $y=0$ we get that $x=-1\not\in \mathbb{N}$ so the function is not surjective.It's injective since for all $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ implies $x_1=x_2$ since $x_1+1=x_2+1\implies x_1=x_2$